# find: ‘/proc/5110’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, find, cd

I modified a find and cd command I found on the internet, it works, it finds the folder and changes dir, but it puts out the error and it's bugging me.

Command (running as root):

```
cd "$(find / -type d -name "nkn-node")" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Error output (sometimes more than one):

```
find: ‘/proc/5110’: No such file or directory
```

---

EDIT:
Command (running as root), if you redirect both, "cd" doesn't work

```
cd "$(find / -type d -name "nkn-node" > /dev/null 2>&1)" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Could somebody please help solve this please.

Thank you

Comment: The output of `cd` is redirected, the output of `find` is not.

Comment: Maybe you ought to reveal what "foldernametofind" actually stands for.

Comment: Btw., you do realize that theoretically your find command could return more than one file, do you.

Comment: @Roadowl yes, but now on a fresh server where this is being deployed, is there any was to be more precise? like searching /onedir/twodir for precision?

Comment: `find` output is not redirected here.

Comment: @Roadowl If the output of find is redirected the cd doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I repeat, find's output is NOT redirected here.

Comment: If it would, you wouldn't see that error ;-)

Comment: @Roadowl i understand, and I tried doing it, but when find is redirected "cd" stops working. I'm trying to figure out what causes the find error in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd "$(find / -type d -name "nkn-node" 2>/dev/null)"
```

Should get rid of the "error" (which is just a warning).

To address the question about a more granular search that you then posed in the comments:

```
cd "$(find /dir1 /dir2 /dir3 /...  -type d -name "nkn-node" 2>/dev/null)"
```

Comment: You're welcome @no112358  ... as for the change:  to be able to make use of the found directory as a target you can't suppress the "normal" output of find (which is what `2>&1` does. I simply redirected the error output `2>` ...

Comment: I didn't even notice that, heh thanks for letting me know.